# Java variable is out of scope even though I've already declared it in the class?

Tags: java, variables

My compiler keeps saying that 'cents' in my toString method is out of scope, but I don't understand why this is because I've already declared it in the class.

Here is my code:

```
public class Currency
{
private Double value;

// Constructor
public Currency(Double startValue)
{
    value = startValue;
}

// Sets value to newValue
public void setValue(Double newValue)
{
    value = newValue;
}

// Returns the dollar portion of value
// if value is 12.34, returns 12
public Integer getDollars()
{
return value.intValue();
}

// Returns the cents portion of value
// as an Integer
// if value is 12.34, returns 34
public Integer getCents()
{
Integer cents = (int)(value * 100) % 100;
return cents;
}

// Returns a String representation
// in the format
// $12.34
public String toString()
{
return "$" + value + cents;
}
```

}

Comment: No you didn't `cents` only exists in method `getCents`

Comment: `cents` is a local variable in your `getCents` method.

Comment: `return "$" + getDollars() + "." + getCents();` would be a much better way of implementing `toString()`.

Comment: *" ... because I've already declared it in the class"* - Actually, you declared it inside a method.  Therefore it is a *local* variable, and out of scope in *other* methods.

Comment: Note that Java doesn't have implicit properties: even though you've created a `get` method doesn't mean that you can access it by just typing `cents` (and, if a property was created, you would probably expect `Cents` instead, case matters).

Comment: Another few notes: generally we use `double` and `int` instead of their objectified instances called `Double` and `Integer`. I'm not sure of the class name; dollars is just one type of currency after all, and not all types of currencies have "cents" the same way as dollars have.

Answer (score 0):

as you want two precision(i.e format value in %.2f) for value you can consider using something like below

```
 // Returns a String representation in the format  $12.34
    public String toString()
    {
    return "$" + String.format("%.2f", value) ;
    }

    // main class

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        Currency c = new Currency(12.3423456d);
        System.out.println("Cents: "+c.getCents());

        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

Output:
Cents: 34
$12.34